# how to store NSString in Stack

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, stack

I create stack class in my program that I want store NSString value in that.
this is stack class :

```
@interface Stack : NSObject
- (void)push:(id)obj;
- (id)pop;
- (BOOL)isEmpty;
@end
@implementation Stack
{
    NSMutableArray *stack;
}
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];   
    if(self!= nil){
        stack = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}
- (void)push:(id)obj
{
    [stack addObject:obj];
}
- (id)pop
{
    id lastobj = [stack lastObject];
    [stack removeLastObject];
    return lastobj;
}
- (BOOL)isEmpty
{
    return stack.count == 0;
}
@end
```

also I have another class with name : TableViewController
I want when to click on cell in TableViewController store cell's id that receive from URL

this is my code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{
    // I want that xCode value with xCode2 value push in stack 

    NSLog(@"Row in Tab : %d",indexPath.row);

    if ([Folder containsObject:[All objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]) {
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://192.168.1.%d/mamal/filemanager.php?dir=%@&folder=%d&id",IP,xCode,indexPath.row]];
        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        NSURLResponse *response = nil;
        NSError *err = nil;
        NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];
        NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[data bytes] length:[data length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        xCode2 = responseString;          //this is new cell's id.I want to push this value in stack
        NSLog(@"xcode : %@", xCode2);

        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segue4" sender:self];
    }

    else
    {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segue3" sender:self];

    }
}
```

in top code I want when to click on cell push two value in stack (xCode & xCode2) but I dont know about to use of stack.

Comment: Where did you implement `addObject:` etc? I guess you wanted to inherit from `NSMutableArray` instead of `NSObject`. Then remove the `stack=...`  statement from the `init` method.

Comment: my friend I to use push segue and I have a global variable that send data to next page when I go to next page and want to return pervious page this variable not return!!!

Answer (score 1):

1. you need a variable that holds your stack.. i'd make it a member var:

   ```
   @implementation TableViewController {
       Stack *_stack;
   }
   ...
   ```
2. then when the cell is clicked, push the value

   ```
   ...
   if(!_stack)
       _stack = [[Stack alloc] init];
   [_stack push:xcode2];
   ...
   ```

Comment: my friend how I pop object in stack

Comment: this answers the question but may not be what you want ... actually I don't get what you want but this in itself isn't useful

Comment: please tell me complete . I want when go on this page auto pop last obj from stack for example 10 and 11 id store in stack when I go on to this page pop 11 id and I to be can use 10 id

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Daij-Djan has suggested, do the following:

```
@interface Stack : NSMutableArray
- (void)push:(id)obj;
- (id)pop;
- (BOOL)isEmpty;
@end
@implementation Stack

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];   
    if(self!= nil){
      // Perform any initialization here. If you don't then there is no point in implementing init at all. 
    }
    return self;
}
- (void)push:(id)obj
{
    [self addObject:obj];
}
- (id)pop
{
    id lastobj = [self lastObject];
    [self removeLastObject];
    return lastobj;
}
- (BOOL)isEmpty
{
    return [self count] == 0;
}
@end
```